# How to add multiple filters when using Django Rest framework search_filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently trying to create a fullstack website using django for the backend. One of the features I'm building is a search function. To do that, I used the built in django-rest SearchFilter, as well as the built in OrderingFilter so users can toggle how results are ordered. However, I also want users to be able to filter their results further, such as selecting a specific year, or a specific name, from a drowdown menu. So essentially, I want to be able to use a search filter and still specify another field that has to match exactly. For example, lets say the users searched for "Cat" and the results were as follows:

---

Name: Cat1
Description: A happy cat
Year: 2017

---

Name: Cat2
Description: A sad cat
Year: 2017

---

Name: Lion
Description: A large cat
Year: 2018

---

Name: Lion
Description: A large cat
Year: 2019

All of these results show up because they contain "cat" in either the name or description fields. But then, I want the user to be able to specify a year via a dropdown menu. So the menu would have 2017, 2018 and 2019 as options, and after selecting 2017, the results would be like this:

---

Name: Cat1
Description: A happy cat
Year: 2017

---

Name: Cat2
Description: A sad cat
Year: 2017

With the other years filtered out. I can't do this on the front end, because the database I'm working with has thousands of entries, meaning the results are returned in pages. This seems like a fairly straightforward problem, but none of the things I've tried have worked. Does anyone know the best way to approach this?

Here's the database model for the objects that are being searched:

```
class Measure(OverrideModel):

year = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField()

class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=["duration", "code"],
            name=prefix("measure", "duration_code_uniq"),
        )
    ]
```

And here is the current view I'm using:

```
class MeasureSearchViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Measure.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MeasureSerializer
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter, SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ["name", "description"]
    ordering_fields = ["duration", "name"]

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_serializer(
            *args, program=self.program, tag=False, **kwargs
        )
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine search and filter mechanisms. Apart from defining `search_fields`You need to add `filter_fields` attribute to your ViewSet and add `DjangoFilterBackend` to `filter_backends` list:

```py
class MeasureSearchViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Measure.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MeasureSerializer
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter, SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ["name", "description"]
    ordering_fields = ["duration", "name"]
    filterset_fields = ['year'] # enable filtering by year

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_serializer(
            *args, program=self.program, tag=False, **kwargs
        )
```

You can get more info at: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#generic-filtering

Comment: Hey, I tried adding this to my viewset, and then modified the url I was using to call it to "api/?search=CAT&Year=2017" but it doesn't seem to be working, as I still get results from other years. Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: After playing around with it more, it appears that if I take out the fitler_backends, search_fields and ordering_fields, then the filterset_fields works. If I take out the filterset_fields, then the other work, but if I have both only the ordering and search filters work, and the fitlerset_fields don't work at all

Comment: Wait I think I found the solution.  Apparently you need to explicitly add DjangoFilterBackend to fitler_backends in order to use both together

Comment: I edited my solution according to your notes.